# Is any parallel set preserving map affine?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, affine-geometry

I'm going over some lecture notes (http://www.math.umd.edu/~wmg/pgom.pdf, PG.7 definition 1.1 and exercise 1.2) that states that a map is affine if and only if parallel sets are parallel under the map.

The given definition of parallel sets are that $A,B$ are parallel if there exists a translation $g$ such that $g(A) = B$.

The problem I have with this is that affine maps must also preserve lines. Does is necessarily follow from $A||B \implies f(A)||f(B)$ that $f$ preserves lines? I am having trouble finding a counter example for maps between spaces of dimension greater than 1, but intuitively it seems unlikely that this property is strong enough to guarantee preservation of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For any line $l$, let $a,b,c$ be any three evenly spaced points on $l$. Then $A=\{a,b\}$ and $B=\{b,c\}$ are parallel.